# unordered_multimap::equal_range slow

Tags: c++, g++, tr1, unordered-map

I would expect unordered_multimap::equal_range to be in average constant complexity, however the following does not scale linearly with n as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std::tr1;
using namespace std;

int main(){
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        unordered_map<int, int> um;
        for(int i=0; i<n; ++i){
                um.insert(make_pair(i%100000, i));
                pair<unordered_map<int, int>::iterator,unordered_map<int,int>::iterator > t = um.equal_range(i);
        }
}
```

```
$ g++ testbr.cpp
$ time echo 10000 | ./a.out 

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.003s
$ time echo 100000 | ./a.out 

real    0m4.492s
user    0m4.490s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:**
Without equal_range it scales perfectly as expected.
Also if I insert all elements with the same key 0 (and alway call equal_range(0)) it scales as expected, even though boost doc states that equal range is in average O(count(k))...?

Comment: Time it with the `equal_range` line commented out. It might be the `insert` that's taking the time. In general to work out why a hashmap is misbehaving, look at the `bucket_count` and the number of elements in each bucket -- you'd expect this example to be evenly distributed, but I suppose maybe you've hit `max_bucket_count`. I'd hope not.

Comment: You should always profile an optimised build. What do you get if you compile with `-O3`?

Comment: with -O3 100.000 is 30 times slower than 10.000 - so it is better but not nice

Comment: max_bucket_count is 357913941 on the system I used to test this - so I'm not even close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in libstdc++, I cannot find a bug report anywhere, but with `#include <unordered_map>` and compilation with `-std=c++11` I get the expected behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

This doesn't scale `O(n)`, but `O(n * n)` (you're calling `std::equal_range` `n` times)!

Move the `std::equal_range` out of the inner loop.

Comment: According to boost documentation equal_range should be in average count(k), which is 1 in my case! Strange enough it becomes a lot faster if I insert all elements in the same key, so that count(k)==n

Comment: The count doesn't stay 1. The total running time is approx. `1+2+3+...+n`.

Comment: @nightcracker: `k` is the size of the equal range, i.e. the number of elements in the container with that key. The key is `i % 100000`, which is equal to `i` in this example since `i < n <= 100000`. So every element in the container has a distinct key. The count stays 1, so `equal_range` *should* only take time proportional to the size of the container in the degenerate case of over-full buckets.

Comment: @SteveJessop: doesn't the size of the container itself increase by 1 each iteration? And according to cppreference, in the worst case, equal_range takes time proportional to the container size. So, in the worst case, that's 1 in the first iter, 2 in the second, etc. Total running time: 1+2+3+...+n = n(n+1)/2.

Comment: @nightcracker: yes, and as I said the worst performance should only happen in the degenerate case where the hash function has failed to distribute the elements between the buckets. On average for a typical case it should be `O(count(k))`. There was a typo in what I wrote above, `count(k)` is the size of the range returned by `equal_range(k)`, but I wrote "`k` is the size". Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: Yes, worst case is O(n^2), I just dont understand why my test is a "worst case". Evenly distributed integers seem like a perfect workload for a hashtable to me?